# Cross-browser datepicker format in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, jquery-ui

To get Chrome and other browsers that support Html5 date natively to show a datepicker I need to put these attributes on the date property in the model:

```cs
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        public DateTime? From { get; set; }
```

For other browsers I use the datepicker from jQuery UI.

I have set up the datepicker to use the dd.MM.yyyy format, dd.MM.yyyy.

It works as long as the users clicks the field and chooses a date, 
but when there is data in the field from the server-side it is shown in the yyyy-MM-dd  format and is not chosen as the default value when the datepicker is opened.

How do I show the dates in the dd.MM.yyyy format when it has to be sent from the server in the yyyy-MM-dd format for it to work with native html5 datepicker?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
                $.datepicker.setDefaults(
                    $.extend(
                    {
                        'dateFormat': 'mm.dd.yy',
                        'altFormat': 'yy-mm-dd'
                    },
                    $.datepicker.regional['no']
                    )
                    );              
                $("#From").datepicker().val();
                $("#To").datepicker();
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/Home/Date" method="post">        
        <label for="From">From: </label>
        <input id="From" name="From" type="date" value="2014-09-23" />
        <label for="To">To: </label>
        <input id="To" name="To" type="date" value="2014-10-09" />        
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome this uses the native date-picker and formats the date according to Chromes settings.

[image: Chrome]

In Firefox it renders like this:

[image: Firefox]

After you have clicked in a field and chosen a date it uses the format I want, dd.MM.yyyy

Is there a way to force the jQuery datepicker to format the included data on page load?

Comment: Try this trick: create another hidden datepicker with format `yyyy-MM-dd`. When u read/send data, just use `getDate & setDate` sync two datepicker.

Comment: Why don't you set the date format in the jquery datepicker? So the server and the client both uses the same format?

Comment: I do set the date format in datepicker and everything works perfectly once the user actually clicks the datepicker.
The problem is that it shows the wrong format before the user clicks the date field.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current culture in your Global.asax file, for application level For Example You can try any format you wanted,

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```